# Gnu grub when installing ubuntu on a usb flash drive

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I have a 64 GB USB flash drive that I installed Ubuntu on so I can plug it into any computer and boot to it, but I cant find it in the bios as a boot option. I used an old laptop to install Linux onto the USB and whenever i turn off the laptop there is this thing called gnu grub that is only on the laptop, I assume I need this to boot off the USB so how do i get it to be portable? or how do I boot off the USB with out it?

Comment: When you install Ubuntu you are asked where to install grub.  It sounds like you installed it to the old-laptop's hdd, which means the USB thumb-drive will only boot in that laptop (ie. you should have selected whatever device the thumb-drive is on as your location for grub).  GRUB is the GNU bootloader used by Ubuntu and other OSes and lets you choose which you want to boot (a multiboot setup) or if you want to boot older kernels, stage 0 is written to the MBR of a device which you specify (the question was asking which device to write MBR to)

Comment: Boot it on the laptop (as it's easy), the `sudo grub-install /dev/sdx` (where sdx is the device for your flash-drive) which will write the MBR to the flash drive.  Then you'll have to do the same with your laptop (ie. use whatever OS exists on that to take ownership, or write it's own MBR code on to the laptop's hdd's first sector)  The commands to fix the laptop will vary on what OS (and version if it runs windows) is running on it

Comment: I believe its /sdb but how i check if that's the right USB?

Comment: `lsblk` will give you a list of block devices recognized; though if it's mounted (ie. in use) `mount` will show you what is is mounted (ie. if you're using it as /; I'd likely use that to verify it's what I want). (I'll mention `blkid` too as sometimes I use that as well; it lists UUID's for block devices).  Please note sdx letters can vary from machine to machine, or on the same machine when you change bios settings..

Comment: I have ran the command and installed grub on the correct drive returning "No errors" so how do I actually boot from it? every time i boot off the USB from the bios (different PC from the laptop I used to initially installed Linux on the USB) it goes into windows automatic repair.

Comment: Does the old laptop has legacy BIOS and the new PC has UEFI?

Comment: I believe so yes.